# Why does the font-size in html sometimes dynamically changes based on different viewport and sometimes does not?

Tags: html, google-chrome, font-size, responsiveness

I was testing some of my html pages readability on mobile devices and discovered that in some parts of the html my **text is shrinking** on the mobile devices depending on the viewport size (browser dynamically changes the font-size value of the text - no JavaScript, no media queries, nothing.. just plain html) and in other parts **does not**.

I was trying to understand what did I do in my code that causes this, so I started to strip down my code step by step until getting the minimal possible code which shows the threshold between when it still does the dynamical adjustments and when it doesn't anymore.

I end up with the two codes (see below): index.html which does that and index2.html which doesn't.

You can replicate this behavior when opening the codes below, going to *Developer tools* in Chrome, selecting *Device Mode* and choosing *Dimensions: Responsive*. Now if you go to *Calculated* tab and search for **font-size** value, you will see that all the `<li>` tags (and only those) are dynamically changing the font-size value as you increase or decrease the width dimension of the simulated device.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
          <ul>
            <li>
              Title 1
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 3 sssssss</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              Title 2
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              Title 3
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
            <ul>
              <li>
                Title 3  sssssssssssss
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"
                        >Item 1 sssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssss</a
                      >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"
                        >Item 2 ssssssssss ssssssssss ssssssssssssssss
                        sssssssssssss</a
                      >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Item 3 sssssss sssssssssssssssss</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

and index2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
          <ul>
            <li>
              Title 1
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 3 ssssss</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              Title 2
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              Title 3
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
            <ul>
              <li>
                Title 3  sssssssssssss
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"
                        >Item 1 sssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssss</a
                      >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"
                        >Item 2 ssssssssss ssssssssss ssssssssssssssss
                        sssssssssssss</a
                      >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Item 3 sssssss sssssssssssssssss</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Both files are identical, only the second one has one `<li>` item **shorter by one character!**. "Item 3 ssssss" has 6 S's instead of 7. Nothing else. That is all!!

I know the Chrome's *Device Mode* is just a simulation of mobile devices' behavior, so in order to make sure this is not just some glitch in the simulation, I have uploaded both files online to be able to test it on a real mobile devices:

[First file](https://atarian.wz.cz/tests/index.html)

[Second file](https://atarian.wz.cz/tests/index2.html)

**Anybody can explain this?**

If I knew how to make any of my code dynamically change the font-size on purpose like in the first file, it would be a great functionality and I would not need any of those complicated media queries. But at this point, it is happening just by accident and I don't understand why.

Thank you!

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the note. The '/>' is added there automatically by Visual Studio Code code formatter. :) Even if delete that, it still saves it there...

Comment: You would think the VS Code people would take a glancing look at the HTML standard at least. After all, Microsoft helped write and edit it.